# How does automatic de-referencing work in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am trying to learn Rust and am having some trouble understanding why we need to dereference pointers in some cases and not in others. Fishing for answers online, I found out that Rust has automatic dereferencing, but I couldn't find much on the topic. Can someone explain to me how this exactly works?

To make it more specific, here is a sample code where I encountered this problem.

```
fn mode(v: &mut Vec<i32>) -> Option<i32> {
    let mut map: HashMap<i32, i32> = HashMap::new();
    let mut max = (0, 0);
    if v.is_empty() {
        return None;
  
    } else {
        ();
  
    }
    for i in v {
        let count = map.entry(*i).or_insert(0);
        *count += 1;
  
    }
    for (k, v) in map.iter() {
        if v > &max.1 {
            max = (*k, *v);
           } else {
            ();
  
        }
  
    }
    Some(max.0)
```

Here, there is apparantely no need to dereference vector v anywhere, but we need to dereference several other variables such as i in line 75, and I do not understand why.

Comment: `is_empty(&self)` needs a reference on self. `v` is already a reference (`&mut Vec`), so there is no need to dereference. `i in v` calls `into_iter(self) where self is &Vec` , so there is also no need to derefence. Assigning to `(i32,i32)` needs dereferencing.

Comment: @CoronA It does need to dereference, though, because the `is_empty` method comes from the slice type, not `Vec` itself.  It's usable because `Vec<T>` implements `Deref<Target = [T]>`.  If the compiler didn't auto-deref, you'd have to manually deref the `Vec` to get a slice.

Comment: @cdhowie: I voted up your comment, because I did not check it. But after checking it I cannot find anything wrong with my statement: `is_empty(&self)` is implemented for `Vec<T>` and pasting the code into my IDE also claims that this method is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to illustrate this is within the context of the sample code `x.foo(y)`.

`x` here is the *receiver.*  Given the type of `x`, the compiler has to figure out what function `foo` is.  It attempts to locate `foo` on `x`'s type, and additionally by *auto-dereferencing* `x`, which is what you are asking about.  This process considers the type of `x` as well as every type that is encountered by dereferencing `x` as many times as possible.  (It also considers `&` and possibly `&mut` variants of these types, depending on the mutability of `x` or its reference type.)

If exactly one `foo` is found, then the call is transformed to `T::foo(z, y)` where `T` is the type the `foo` method was located on, and `z` is whatever sequence of dereferences (plus one final, optional `&` or `&mut`) results in a `T`, `&T`, or `&mut T`, as required by `T::foo`.

What about `y`, though?  Arguments undergo [*coercion*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-types), which is a different thing altogether.  The linked documentation lists all of the possible coercions, which I will omit for the sake of brevity, but notably absent are `&T` to `T` and `&mut T` to `T`, one of which would be required to make `map.entry(i)` work in your sample code.  The explicit dereference is therefore required.

Note that one of the items present in the list of coercions is:

> `&T` or `&mut T` to `&U` if `T` implements `Deref<Target = U>`.

Observe that this *doesn't actually dereference a reference* but rather *converts the reference to another type of reference!*  That is, the coercion is `&T` to `&U`, *not* `&T` to `U`.  This is what allows you to give `&String` to an argument that expects a `&str`, for example  (`String` implements `Deref<Target = str>`), but this rule doesn't provide coercion from `&mut i32` to `i32` as would be required to make `map.entry(i)` work.

---

`for i in v` is a completely different scenario; this works simply because `&mut Vec<T>` implements `IntoIterator`.

---

So the answer as to why you don't have to dereference `v` is because you are using it in receiver position, where auto-dereference happens.  Function arguments instead undergo coercion, which has an entirely different set of rules.

Now having said that, in your code `v` is already a reference to a `Vec`, and so `v.is_empty()` could be explained through coercion as well, as this method comes from slices, to which `Vec` automatically dereferences.  However, the overall point still stands -- you cannot conflate auto-dereferencing with deref coercion.  This is one instance where they would happen to do the same thing, but in many other cases they would not.